# Large difference between overall F Score for a custom Spacy NER model and Individual Entity F Score

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I am training a custom NER Model using Spacy on a sample of 5000 text entries with 6 entities. While evaluating the trained model on an unseen sample (500 text entries), the F Score that I get for the overall model (`93.8`) has a large difference between F Score for any individual entities. Can someone help me understand how is the overall F Score calculates and why is there so much difference between overall F Score and individual entity Score?

I built my own custom named entity recognition (NER) model using Spacy.  The size of my training data set was 5000 with 6 entities. Further, I tested my model on 500 samples and evaluated the model using the `Scorer` and `GoldParse`.

Here is my code for evaluating performance on my test data -

```py
def evaluate(ner_model, examples):
    scorer = Scorer()
    for input_, annot in examples:
        doc_gold_text = ner_model.make_doc(input_)
        gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, entities=annot.get('entities'))
        pred_value = ner_model(input_)
        scorer.score(pred_value, gold)
    return scorer.scores
```

Here is the result that I get -

```
{'uas': 0.0, 'las': 0.0, 'ents_p': 93.62838106164233, 'ents_r': 
 93.95728476332452, 'ents_f': 93.79254457050243,
 'ents_per_type': {
 'ENTITY1': {'p': 6.467595956926736, 'r': 54.51002227171492, 'f': 
 11.563219748420247},
 'ENTITY2': {'p': 6.272470243289469, 'r': 49.219391947411665, 'f': 
 11.126934984520123}, 
 'ENTITY3': {'p': 18.741109530583213, 'r': 85.02742820264602, 'f': 
 30.712745497989392}, 
 'ENTITY4': {'p': 13.413228854574788, 'r': 70.58823529411765, 'f': 
 22.54284884283916}, 
 'ENTITY5': {'p': 19.481765834932823, 'r': 82.85714285714286, 'f': 
 31.546231546231546}, 
'ENTITY6': {'p': 24.822695035460992, 'r': 64.02439024390245, 'f': 35.77512776831346}},
 'tags_acc': 0.0, 'token_acc': 100.0}
```

Here you can see a large difference between `ents_f` and `f` for any other entity type. What is the relationship of the overall F Score of the model with individual entity scores?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug that should be fixed in the next release. You can see the details here: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3968

Comment: I see. Looks like the case. Thanks for the link @aab

Comment: You can also try compiling from most recent version of spaCy and install it. See https://spacy.io/usage#source. Another temporary hack would be to just copy the most recent version of scrorer.py in your project and use that Scorer class instead of scorer class from spaCy's source code.

Comment: Note that the current version still has at least one additional bug (it doesn't count entity types that are in gold but not found in the doc), but hopefully that will be fixed soon, too.

Comment: Thanks, @FallakAsad

It worked for me.

I have one more question. How is the overall F Score of the model calculated? Is Is it the average of all the individual F Scores?

Comment: I don't think it's the average of all individual entities. 
After updating Scorero.py - My overall F Score is 93.79254457050243

And my Individual F Scores are - 
Entity 1 -  94.01503759398496
Entity 2 - 90.97118165661917
Entity 3 - 99.02774315324619
Entity 4 - 94.99593637524671
Entity 5 - 97.8927203065134
Entity 6 - 90.40767386091126

Average of these do not match the overall F Score!